# Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back reference property found

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have two model classes. One is

```
@Entity(name = "userTools")
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "assignToUser_id","toolsType_id" }))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserTools {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private ToolsType toolsType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userTools", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<UserToolsHistory> userToolsHistory;
}
```

and the second is

```
@Entity(name = "userToolsHistory")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserToolsHistory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private ToolsType toolsType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserTools userTools; 

    private String comments;
}
```

But on save I'm getting this error:

```
Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back
reference property found from type [collection type; class
java.util.List, contains [simple type, class
com.dw.model.tools.UserToolsHistory]]
```

Answer (score 11):

In order to make troubleshooting easier, you can add a different name to each `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`, for example:

```
@JsonManagedReference(value="userToolsHistory")
    private List<UserToolsHistory> userToolsHistory;
```

This way the error is more meaningful because it prints the reference name instead of 'defaultReference'.

Please indicate which enity you are trying to serialize - `UserTools` or `UserToolsHistory`? Anyway you can try adding getters and setters to your entities and then add `@JsonIgnore` to the "get{Parent}()" in the "child" class.

Answer (score 9):

The exception you are facing stems from the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

To fix it swap the annotations so you get this :

```
public class UserTools {
...
@JsonBackReference
private List<UserToolsHistory> userToolsHistory;
...
}

public class UserToolsHistory {
....    
@JsonManagedReference
private UserTools userTools; 
----
}
```

This tutorial explains how it must be done : [jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Comment: I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469722/how-to-make-pojo-and-parse-recursive-objects-using-jackson) where I need to parse recursive field and looks like maybe I need to use `@JsonManagedReference` but not sure how it's gonna work?

Comment: You can not use Collection, Map, Array or enumeration as @JsonBackReference: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html

Answer (score 6):

`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`  and replacing it with `@JsonIdentityInfo`

Comment: maybe this should not be an answer and simply a comment on the question/answer

Comment: don't comments, because reputation <50