# Reading Json with Inheritance

Tags: java, json, jackson, reader

I am trying to read a Json file in Java. But I have no idea how to distribute the data that contains the Java file to the subclasses. 
I have a superclass and then I have three subclasses, which depending on the data provided I have to fill or not, and I do not know how to fill these three subclasses (that extends the superclass) depending on the data of the provided file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make POJO and parse recursive objects using jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469722/how-to-make-pojo-and-parse-recursive-objects-using-jackson)

Comment: you should post some code to show what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Refer this https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample example on how this can be achieved.But keep in mind to do this way, you need to provide type information in the json so it will use the type information to convert json to Java object.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"), 
  @Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck") 
}) // magic happens here, when we give type information using per-class annotations, this will be used by jackson to convert the json to appropriate java objects.
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private String make;
    private String model;

    protected Vehicle(String make, String model) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }

    // no-arg constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Car subclass

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ // any properties from parent that can be ignored })
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    // any properties from this class to be ignored place it above the property
    @JsonIgnore
    private int seatingCapacity;
    private double topSpeed;

    public Car(String make, String model, int seatingCapacity, double topSpeed) {
        super(make, model);
        this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }

    // no-arg constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Truck subclass:

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private double payloadCapacity;

    public Truck(String make, String model, double payloadCapacity) {
        super(make, model);
        this.payloadCapacity = payloadCapacity;
    }

    // no-arg constructor, getters and setters
}
```

wrapper class for reading json which should be same as your json array key.

```
public class VehicleManager {
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

   // setters, getters, no arg constructor
}
```

Main class

```
public class AppStart {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    VehicleManager vehicleManager = new VehicleManager();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try{
    objectMapper.readerFor(VehicleManager.class).readValue(new File("yourJsonFilePath"));
    }
    catch(IOException ie){
      // log an IOException or do some other operation like rethrow, etc.,
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      // log exception
    }

}
}
```

and your sample json should be like

```
"vehicleManager":[{
"type": "car", // type information should be provided here
"make": "Toyota",
"model": "Camry",
"seatingCapacity": 5,
"topSpeed": 168.8

},
{
"type": "car", // type information should be provided here
"make": "Hyundai",
"model": "Elantra",
"seatingCapacity": 5,
"topSpeed": 178.8

}]
```